# PIVOT over two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

is there a more elegant way to implement a PIVOT on the following table - basically I am trying to count the typeid's for ever userid, as well as get the first value for each type and pivot the types and the values (using sql server 2012):

[image]

This is the expected result:

[image]

And here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT  userid ,
        MAX([1]) [1] ,
        MAX([2]) [2] ,
        MAX(value1) [value1] ,
        MAX(value2) [value2]
FROM    ( SELECT    userid ,
                    typeid ,
                    FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER ( PARTITION BY userid, typeid ORDER BY testid ) [value] ,
                    'value' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), typeid) [valuepivot]
          FROM      dbo.test
        ) t PIVOT( COUNT(typeid) FOR typeid IN ( [1], [2] ) ) as pivottype
        PIVOT( MAX(value) FOR [valuepivot] IN ( [value1], [value2] ) ) as pivottype2
GROUP BY userid
```

Table Schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
            PIVOT( MAX(value) FOR [valuepivot] IN ( [value1], [value2] ) ) as pivottype2
    [TestID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) 
    GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select userid,
       sum(case when typeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as test1,
       sum(case when typeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as test2,
       max(case when typeid = 1 then value end) as test1,
       max(case when typeid = 2 then value end) as test2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, typeid order by testid) as seqnum
      from test
     ) t
group by userid;
```

Whether it is simpler or not is a matter of opinion.